# I want to pick an image from the galary and want to reduce the size of the same image and need to save it in separate directory?

Tags: android

I've already succeeded in fetching an image from the galary but I'm not able to reduce the size of the image and save it in separate directory. so how can i reduce its size in kbs and save it?

please help.

My code is:

```
public class PickImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

ImageView iv;
Button imageButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_image);


    imageButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnPicker);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pickImage();
        }
    });
}

private void pickImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions out there, you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to resize image:

```
Bitmap bm=Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .override(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
    . into(-1,-1).get();
```

or try this solutions to write the resized bitmap

1. [How to compress images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5932708/4091231)
2. [How to compress image size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18545337/4091231)

And after that save the bitmap where you need it